# Solution of Whittaker-Hill-like differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions

In my work, I derived an equation that looks like this:

\begin{align}
y''+(A+\epsilon\sin\Omega t+B\sin\omega t)y=C\cos\omega t
\end{align}
where $\epsilon\ll1$. This is similar to the Whittaker-Hill differential equation, except $\omega$ may not be equal to $2\Omega$. I am wondering the best way to go about solving this. I have two ideas.

**Idea 1**

As $\epsilon<<1$, we can solve the equation perturbatively. Therefore, if we let $y=y_0+\epsilon y_1$, then we find the differential equations of

\begin{align}
y_0''+(A+B\sin\omega t)y_0=C\cos\omega t
\end{align}
\begin{align}
y_1''+(A+B\sin\omega t)y_1=-y_0\sin\Omega t
\end{align}

These look like Mathieu differential equations with a forcing term. However, I'm not sure how to solve the resulting equations. I tried doing a literature search, but the generalizations of the Mathieu differential equation I found tended to be on including non-linear terms, such as in [here](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~rand/randpdf/AMR.pdf) and [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11071-005-4338-y). I have also found a paper considering $\epsilon=B$, but in my case, this is not necessarily true.

**Idea 2**

As the top equation looks like the Whittaker-Hill differential equation, then perhaps there is a generalization of it that I can use. However, I have not found anything useful.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can use [variation of parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters) to solve an inhomogeneous second-order linear differential equation in terms of integrals involving the fundamental solutions of the homogeneous equation.  I don't know if the integrals in this case can be done in closed form, though.